# Tomcat web project deployment

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

*Hello*,

Now I'm trying to deploy my maven project with tomcat but getting error:

When I type command:

`mvn tomcat7:deploy`

I get:

`Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused (Connection refused) -> [Help 1]`

I have this plugin in my **pom.xml**:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <url>http://localhost:8000/</url>
      <server>tomcatserver</server>
      <path>/</path>
      <port>8000</port>
      <update>true</update>
      <username>tomcat</username>
      <password>tomcat</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also, I have this roles and users in **tomcat-users.xml**:

```xml
<!-- My roles -->
  <role rolename="tomcat"></role>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"></role>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"></role>
  <role rolename="manager-script"></role>

<!-- My users -->
  <user username="tomcat" password="****" roles="tomcat,manager-gui,admin-gui,manager-script"/>
  <user username="fedotsoldier" password="****" roles="manager-script,admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

This is my **settings.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>tomcatserver</id>
      <username>tomcat</username>
      <password>tomcat</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

You can see full stack trace here:

```sh
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.774 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-23T18:10:13+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project webproject: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused (Connection refused) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project webproject: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute (AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute (AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:68)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:591)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket (PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection (DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open (ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect (DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute (DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute (AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.invoke (TomcatManager.java:742)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deployImpl (TomcatManager.java:705)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deploy (TomcatManager.java:388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar (AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager (AbstractDeployMojo.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute (AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:132)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute (AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:68)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

---

I have read many different tips and guides, but no one helped me.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:591)
```

It means it cannot connect to the tomcat manager app to deploy as you set its `<url>` incorrectly. The default should look likes [http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Supported_Manager_Commands). So change to :

```
<url>http://localhost:8000/manager/text</url>
```

Comment: I changed address to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text`, but it keeps giving me an exception

Comment: you are using 8000 or 8080 ? I see you use 8000 as you mention in your question....

Comment: Ok, I'm using 8000. Anyway, changing port number in address didn't help me